# Is it possible to add dialog box for uninstallation in wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to add customized dialog box for uninstallation of my application. 
I have also tried the following:

```
<InstallUISequence>
   <Show Dialog="RemoveDlg" OnExit="success">REMOVE="ALL"</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Is it possible or not in wix? Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can certainly author dialogs that are specific to product removal, uninstallations started from the remove button in Add or Remove Programs (now Programs and Features) are run without the UI sequence, and thus will not show these dialogs. One common alternative is to set the ARPNOREMOVE property which then requires the end user to click Modify instead of Remove. The modify button starts maintenance, which does show your UI.

Comment: Thanx Michael,..But can you please give me some idea how can i use this alternative..because i am already tried to set this property to 1.but could not understand how can i set the dialog box on Modify..
Thanx once again.

Comment: Michael, i have a doubt that my custom action is not working well at maintenance mode in wix..Actually i want to clear\delete some data from my %appdata%\product\ ..can u help me to do this?

Comment: If you want to know what's happening at uninstall, take a verbose log. Then search for your custom action's name, and you can find out if it executed, or was skipped due to condition, or just doesn't show up. As far as %appdata%, just remember that you can remove only from the current user's %appdata% folder, so uninstall may not be the best time for this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the data in %appdata%\product\ can cause problems for a re-installation of the application I would recommend leaving it in place on uninstall. Whatever you install in this folder is considered user data, and should not be automatically removed by default - and often not as an option either. Many companies apply custom permissioning on the userprofile folders. Messing around in there could cause your MSI to hickup seriously - particularly on terminal servers by triggering self-repair (which is generally not allowed on TS).

Keep in mind that the same installation sequence is used for install, uninstall and patching. If you use major upgrade patches that essentially uninstall and reinstall the product you could end up deleting the user data and reinstalling it for every installation. If this is acceptable, the data you deal with is not user data, and is hence located in the wrong place on disk.

If you run a delete operation towards the end of the uninstall via a custom action that checks exit code, you could trigger rollback of the uninstall, essentially causing the product to be reinstalled and be impossible to uninstall! Rare, but it  happens. If the custom action is run after InstallFinalize and hence outside the MSI install sequence your setup could return an uninstall error code and leave your product broken and the uninstall incomplete or your product partially unregistered.

In short I wouldn't mess around with this. If you have insistent customers I wouldn't mess with a dialog if I could help it. I would add a PUBLIC property to control whether a custom action is run immediately prior to InstallFinalize. Flush any error return codes and write information into the MSI log instead. Then users could uninstall user data by specifying the property on the command line or hard code it in the Property table.

If you have to have a GUI you can use the same property to set from a custom dialog to control whether deletion is done or not. Remember to condition the display of the dialog with care. I.E don't show it during patching operations.